# MATLAB Syntax for classdef

Tags: matlab, definition

I'm not new to MATLAB, however I have never worked with classes in MATLAB. Looking at some implementation code, which I cannot share due to the license agreement, I have encountered a line on top of *.m file that defines class in following way:

```
classdef A < b.c
```

My guess is that it defines class `A` that belongs to each `c` of structure `b`. However, I am not sure, especially about `<`. Could anyone explain it to me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the syntax for a subclass definition. You will find the extensive documentation here:

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/subclass-constructors.html

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you!